# On $ \int e^{|x|} \:dx $

Tags: integration

Can we say that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{|x|}\:dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-x}\:dx +\int_0^{\infty}e^{x}\:dx =2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\:dx?$

Comment: You cannot say anything as this integral diverges.

Comment: i think it is $$\infty$$

Comment: If you had $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$, then you'd be able to do something.

Answer (score 0):

One may recall that, for any *integrable* *even* function $f$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\:dx&=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)\:dx+\int_0^\infty f(x)\:dx
\\\\&=\int_{\infty}^0f(-x)\:(-dx)+\int_0^\infty f(x)\:dx
\\\\&=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\:dx+\int_0^\infty f(x)\:dx
\\\\&=2\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\:dx.
\end{align}
$$ In the considered case, one may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-A}^B e^{|x|}\:dx&=\int_{-A}^0 e^{-x}\:dx+\int_0^B e^{x}\:dx
\\\\&=e^A-1+e^B-1
\\\\&=e^A+e^B-2
\end{align}
$$ which tends to $\infty$ as $A$ and $B$ tend to $\infty$.